# Does the series $f'(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} -\frac{1}{n} e^{-nx} \cos(e^{-nx})$ converge uniformly or pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would say no, since for $x < 0$, $f'(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ since $e^{-nx} \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. So the series doesn't even converge for $x < 0$.

Also $f'(0) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} -\frac{1}{n} \cos(1)$ which would seem to diverge to $-\infty$.

Correct?

Comment: You have answered your own question.  The series converges uniformly on all compact subsets of $[\delta,\infty)$, $\delta>0$.  And the series converges pointwise on $(0,\infty)$.  But the series diverges on $(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: Additional remark: writing the $\cos$ in exponential form you can do the sum explicitly for $x\gt 0$ with the result $\frac{1}{2} \left(-\log \left(1-e^{(-1-i) x}\right)-\log \left(1-e^{(-1+i) x}\right)\right)$ This function now can be continued analytically, specifically to the region $x\lt 0$.

Comment: @MarkViola How would I argue that it diverges for $x < 0$? It seemed obvious at first, but since $\cos(e^{-nx})$ switches between positive and negative I'm not sure

Comment: @goblinb For a series to converge, it is necessary that the terms of the series tend to zero.  For $x<0$, do the terms approach $0$?

Comment: @MarkViola No, it seems they just go all over the place

Comment: @goblinb And so, what can you conclude regarding convergence of the series of terms that do not approach zero?

Comment: @MarkViola If the terms do not approach zero, then the series of terms does not converge

Comment: @goblinb You have it now.